# unChkDsk a decompression bomb

Tags: windows, virus

I'm trying to remove a decompression bomb spotted by Avast from a friend's computer, but I can't make it.

I tried several things :

- MalwareBytes -> clean
- Adwcleaner   -> clean
- BitDefender  -> clean
- HijackThis   -> clean
- navilog1     -> clean
- Avast        -> Decompression Bomb

Now for the context, the bomb has infected his F: (non-external) and replaced his own data by some Apple files (weird since it's not an Apple product) called :

- .fseventsd
- .Spotlight
- .Trahes

in these directories, some -uuid files are there

Otherwise, these dir should not be there, but some other files (movies, games, personnal documents) should (but they're not anymore).

Then, since I was not able to defuse this bomb, I thought than chkdsk would ruin the whole thing without triggering it.

That's what I did and it works.

Using Avast again, I saw that Avast was looking in some

```
FOUND.000X/His_Personnal_File/.../
```

So far, his datas are still there, but not usable since they're just partition fragment by now (after chkdsk).

Then, I tried to use Avira Unerase

Avira UnErase found the documents (all renamed by ?WWW*.*, WWW3620X.AVI for example, indicating that it's a movie he previously had)

But, when I click on a ?WWW* item, and then try to Unerase it, Avira UnErase crashes and the file is not usable.

Do you have any other software/way to unChkDsk them ?

Or a totally different method, I've spent 3 days so far trying to remove it and I can't go further.

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Try Combofix.  You can download it from http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/combofix/   For me it has helped remove some weird malware.

Comment: I'd try it during the day and post the result. Thanks for your advice.